# How to manage folders and layouts in php?

Tags: php, layout

I design and develop websites using php. I use

```
`includes(layouts/header.php);`
```

in every php page across my website. My directory structure is:

```
library         
layouts        ( header, footer, sidebar )
css
js
index.php
about.php
```

but now if I create new dir to keep, say, admin files or staff files or user files in different folders like:

```
library         
layouts        ( header, footer, sidebar )
css
user
     index.php
     login.php
     myaccount.php
js
index.php
about.php
```

Now if I do 
    `include('../layouts/header.php');`

in my file under user dir then I don't get css in the page. That is because the relative path to .css file changes.

I want to know how to manage all this. Is there any way or I have to write new, say, user_header.php in layouts folder?

Answer (score 2):

Use a global variable for site path and combine that with the path of your css file relative to your application root path.

for example in your `header.php` file define:

```
$SITE_PATH = "THE_PATH_TO_YOUR_WEB_APPLICATION/";
```

and then when you want to echo the link tag for css use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<? echo $SITE_PATH;?>css/yourCssFile.css" type="text/css">
```